# Using conditions in jquery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the code block below. Its working for me, but I need to write it with conditions.
Condition mean, I need to add each `span` elements if `item` values is not empty.

```
create: function () {
  $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $('<li class="dropdown-item">')
    .append('<div class="dropdown-item-wrapper">'
           +' <span><span>'+item.item_code+'</span></span>'
           +' <span><span>'+item.brand+'</span></span>'
           +' <span><span>'+item.stock+''+item.unit+'</span></span>'
           +' <span><span>'+item.item_name+'</span></span>'
           +'</div>')                   
    .append('</li>')
    .appendTo(ul); 
}
```

So, I tried it in this way, But I coudn't figure it out.

```
create: function () {
  $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

  var $li  = $('<li class="dropdown-item">');
  var $div = $('<div class="dropdown-item-wrapper">');
  if (item.item_name) {
    $('<span><span>', {text: item.item_name}).appendTo($div); 
  }

  $div.appendTo($li);
  return $li.appendTo(ul); 
}
```

Comment: @devlincarnate, check my updated question. Here I use this code to create custom template for jquery autocomplete. So, values in `item` array may have null values also. Therefor I need check those values before append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional (aka tertiary) operator:

```
+(item.item_name ? (' <span><span>'+item.item_name+'</span></span>') : '')
```